# Margin-Left does not work in the slide show

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have created simple slide show that has 7 div's of 300px width and height. Each div is placed relative to each other. All are placed within a container div of 900px relative to each other with margin left as 10px. Now to slide the images i am changing the margin left.

Case1:
Margin left of all div is 10px;
Now the slider will move the first div by setting its margin-left to -310px.
All other divs follow the first div since they are relative to each other.

Case2:
Now when i set the margin of first div to -620px, Position of other div does not change, same is observed in all other 5 cases. Why is this happening. Please Do explain. Let me if Any other details are required. I haven't added the code since a lot of other things are included withing the slider which will confuse all.

link to jfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=LFTr8KkT3y

Regards,

Comment: Please post a fiddle of your code

Comment: Will try and add in in few minutes

Comment: Useing float:left; and display:inline-block;

Comment: yes i am using float left and display:inner-block

Comment: Hi i have added the fiddle

Comment: ^ Well, it appears broken...

Comment: its seems to be broken because for some strange reason my fiddle is adding prev and next function within window.load function. No idea why this is happening

Comment: Hey i have fixed the fiddle. Please now check and tell me what is issue with marginLeft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `display: inline-block` and `float: left` at the same time on `#slider  div`. The fiddle worked when i removed `float: left`.